# Tag rename request for spelling of TrueType

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There is a standard for fonts named [TrueType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType). There is no space, no hyphen, the same as with, say, JavaScript.

However, there is a tag [true-type-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) instead of [truetype-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/truetype-fonts).

Please could the tag name be corrected, as has already been done on Stack Overflow: [Tag names and gratuitous hyphens—TrueType](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406272/tag-names-and-gratuitous-hyphens-truetype).

Comment: I'm happy I was able to do this without screwing up, as the changes required are destructive and irreversible ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess that if mods have their own badges, then you get "Successfully completed a tag rename." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Please could the tag name be corrected

This is now [status-completed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[true-type-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) has been renamed to (and is now a synonym of) [truetype-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/truetype-fonts)